# Getting null values using HttpClient c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Making a HttpClient Request here :

```
private static void PostPersonInfoAsync1()
{
    Person person = new Person
    {
        Id = "999",
        CompanyName = "ABC",
        Department = "CDE",
        DisplayName = "XYZ",
        JobTitle = "manager",
        OfficeLocation = "zzz"
    };

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
    Console.WriteLine(myContent);
    //var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(myContent);

    stringContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:52810/Person/AddPerson", stringContent).Result;
}
```

This is the where the endpoint hits :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ADD PERSON ::::" + person.ToString());

        string jsonIsSuccess = "";
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonPerson.ToString() + "  is being added");
        //Person person = m_jsonConverter.ConvertToObject(jsonPerson.ToString());
        if (!(person.Id == null || person.JobTitle == null || person.OfficeLocation == null ||
            person.Department == null || person.DisplayName == null || person.CompanyName == null))
        {
            if (m_personRepository.AddPerson(person))
            {
                jsonIsSuccess = "{" +
                    "\"status\":\"success\"" +
                    "}";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jsonIsSuccess = "{" +
                "\"status\":\"failed\"" +
                "}";
        }

        return new JsonResult(jsonIsSuccess);
    }
```

Getting null in all the parameters in the following line

```
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ADD PERSON ::::" + person.ToString());
```

Everything is perfectly fine when I am checking using Postman. But when I created a console app using HttpClient, it's not working.

Comment: is Person class  in client = Person class in api ?

Comment: Try doing `var stringContent = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: yes, they are same.

Comment: so try use public JsonResult AddPerson(string Person) and see if will be hit ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It Gives the same result.

Comment: @d00lar The parameter string is initialized as null for `public JsonResult AddPerson(string Person)`

Comment: Is it a CORS error? Are you sure of that?

Comment: @ShubhamBhattacharjee `person` is a class object. Why are you doing `person.ToString()`? Instead do like this `person.Id.ToString()`. You should be getting class properties by their name.

Comment: Please log the stringContent variable. 
You can also check it in debug mode using breakpoint and check the value of stringContent.

Comment: then try AddPerson( [FromBody] Person person )  or  AddPerson(Dictionary<string, object> person ) or AddPerson( [FromBody]  Dictionary<string, object> person )